# How to use database to suggest questions with api.ai

Tags: javascript, python, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

I am trying to connect database with api.ai to add question suggestion for my bot, but can not find any example, I need code example in javascript or python please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find my example please

html

```
<body>
    <input id="myText" />
</body>
```

jquery

```
$(function () {
    var getData = function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON(
            "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=?&q=" + request.term,
            function (data) {
                response(data);
            });
    };

    var selectItem = function (event, ui) {
        $("#myText").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }

    $("#myText").autocomplete({
        source: getData,
        select: selectItem,
        minLength: 4,
        change: function() {
            $("#myText").val("").css("display", 2);
        }
    });
});
```

with auto comp api: https://autocompleteapi.com/